# Bash script - Need help getting match and substitution working

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to get parameter substitution working in my bash script ... I know I have gotten this all wrong ... I am trying to create a script that will rename a PART of a file.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.hpp; do  mv -v "$3 ${$3/$1/$2}" ; done
```

The error I am getting is:

```
line 2: $3 ${$3/$1/$2}: bad substitution
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what transformation you want to apply to each filename.  Edit your post to include an example (or several examples) of the “before” and “after” filenames.

Comment: And `i` variable is never called !

Comment: Crumbs ... it should be 

for i in *.hpp; do  mv -v "$i ${i/$1/$2}" ; done

Comment: My blunder there ... What am I trying to do - Rename any part of a file ... using mv and parameter substitution 

Foo1_ABC.hpp Foo2_ABC.hpp  Foo3_ABC.hpp 

> test.sh ABC CDG

Foo1_CDG.hpp Foo2_CDG.hpp  Foo3_CDG.hpp 


----

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${$3}` will attempt to interpolate `${"CONTENTS OF $3"}` into a variable.  It is more likely that you want `${3}`.  It is even more likely that you want `${i}`.

Comment: Yes ... I see that ... a series of errors ... on my part. Thanks.

Comment: @Xofo if you have `rename` installed you can just use `rename 's/ABC/CDG/' *.hpp`

Comment: There's different implementations of rename, take care. This is for the perl one

Comment: To be honest everyone says use the rename script ... but it never seems to be there when I want it (on machines that I do not directly manage).


So I wrote:

----

#!/bin/bash
for i in "${@:3}"; do  mv -v "$i" "${i/$1/$2}" ; done
echo "DONE!"

----